# How to activerly listen, agree and express surpise and so on in a converstaion?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, vocabulario

When I'm talking to someone, what are the most common ways to expess agreement, active listening and the like:

"is that so?", "really?", "ohh, I understand", "got it", "ohhh, that makes sense", "definitely so!", "no, no way!", "I can't believe" and so forth.

I mean a colloquial conversation and rather short phrases and words.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few to get you started.

> ¿Ah, sí?
>
> ¡No me digas/diga!
>
> ¿De veras?
>
> ¡Increíble! (this one is not quite so common)
>
> ¡No lo puedo creer!
>
> ¡No es posible!
>
> ¿¡Cómo es posible!?
>
> ¡¿Estás en serio?!
>
> ¡¿En serio?!
>
> Pero ¿¡cómo!?
>
> No...
>
> Sí...
>
> Sí, claro...
>
> Ah, pues sí, claro.
>
> Claro.
>
> Claro que sí.
>
> Claro que no.
>
> Pues sí.
>
> Pues no.
>
> Entiendo.
>
> ¡Eso!
>
> ¡Bravo!

And don't forget to ask

> ¿Cómo te sentiste?

And when the torrent seems to be coming to an end:

> ¿Cómo te sientes ahora? / Y ahora ¿cómo te sientes [pues]?

Comment: **Entiendo** Muchas veces he escuchado "entendido" en lugar de "entiendo."  ¿Es mejor usar uno u otro?  ¿Significan lo mismo?

Comment: @hcbowman - "Entendido" es como "Got it."  Es una abreviatura de "Queda entendido."  Prueba los dos en conversaciones y luego podrás decidir si prefieres el uno o el otro.